# Remove "Link" from new-menu SharePoint modern view

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

[image]I have an issue with the new-menu SharePoint modern page, when i click on to the menu the drop down provides the options as word,ppt, etc and it includes "Link". I know this can be possible using the PnP provisioning but client does not need to using OOTB. Is there any way to edit or remove "Link" from the new-menu.

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: Can you please add any screenshot about which "Link" you are talking about?

Comment: I have included to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB way to remove "Link" in modern library.

Below is a user voice about this topic, you can vote it:
[Disable links in modern library](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/35015383-disable-links-in-modern-library)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i was not looking for OOB i need to edit via library settings or site settings. Possible to explain the user to do it by themselves without code, i had tried with the PnP powershell using this link https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/2019/03/24/programmatically-change-the-new-menu-in-sharepoint-online-using-powershell/